# SQL ERROR LOG is not working properly

Tags: sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyBNy.jpg)Why my sql error log doesn't show the deadlock victim details?? It shows only 1 row victim was spid 319...

```
TraceFlag   Status  Global  Session
1204         1      1        0
1222         1      1        0
```

Comment: You mean you don't get the information you need on what resource was deadlocked? That is annoying, I know ...

Comment: How could i get which was the spid 319? I have the TRC file but SPID=319 does not exist in it...

Comment: That is strange, do you look the right row? The victim is reported as a processId, not a spid, and from other rows you have all the information about the process

Comment: Added the picture, do you see?